# iMessage extension won't run on a device

Tags: ios, iphone, imessage, imessage-extension

I'm developing an iMessage app extension on an existing project. When I run it on a simulator it works just fine. But when I try to run it on a device the status says "Running com.apple.MobileSMS on iPhone", the Messages.app opens up on the device and nothing else happens. I also can't find the app in the iMessage apps "drawer".

I've tried to clean the solution, delete the main app, rebuild it again, and nothing seems to help. Also, the executable for the scheme is set to "Ask on launch", but the dialog to select an app isn't shown when I run the app.

I've searched for a solution but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: What kind of iPhone are you using for testing?

Comment: I've tried with iPhone 5S and 5, both with the latest iOS.

Comment: This may be difficult for SO users to guess at. Can you post screenshots of your project settings and/or scheme options?

Comment: @Zig Can you tell me exactly what part of the project settings?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix the problem by reinstalling the Xcode, apparently it was a bug within it.

Answer (score 1):

You should change deployment target in both - app and extension to the same version.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you very much.